# Record value in first blank cell of a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script to enter the person's name in column A, Age in column B, Height in column C and eye color in column D.

This record should always be made in the first blank cell of each column.

The values to put I want to indicate inside the script itself

```
function Test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Work Test"); 

//Column A
  var lastRow = getLastRow('A1:A');
  var values = getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Test Value A');

//Column B
  var lastRow = getLastRow('B1:B');
  var values = getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Test Value B');

//Column C
  var lastRow = getLastRow('C1:C');
  var values = getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Test Value C');

//Column D
  var lastRow = getLastRow('D1:D');
  var values = getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Test Value D');
}
```

At the moment warning that there is an error in GetLastRow, honestly I do not know much about scripts, I am trying to learn every day and every new tip that I find here by Stack overflow.

I wonder if anyone could help me find the error and what to edit to make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLastRow` isn't a built-in function so you should have to declare it somewhere in your project or use something like

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

Something similar happens with `getRange`. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

Comment: Mate... I find simple solution!
 ```function test() {SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(["Maria","José","Silva","Luíz","Tadeu"]);
                }```

Comment: The question that remains for me is how do I make the script know on which spreadsheet page I specifically want this record?

Because I will do it without the spreadsheet being open, I need to warn which page it will be.

Could you help me with this detail?

Comment: @FredericoMattos Take a look to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

Comment: ```Test  <br/>
Test```        I would like to put here in the comments, the script adjusted so that other people who have the doubt can get it ready. How do I make space between lines? I'm not getting. I've tried to use this way I sent but I can't break the lines.

Comment: @FredericoMattos. If you want to share your solution post it as an answer. Comments are very limited and could be deleted "soon". i.e. break lines aren't allowed